# Symfony 2 Passing Default Date

Tags: php, symfony

I am quite new to Symfony 2.7. I am facing a problem with Symfony form.
Inside my form i have a form field as follows

```
 Builder->add('passDate', 'hidden')
        ->add('issueDate','hidden')
```

Inside my controller function, i need to pass some fix value to database. So here is my form action

```
$entity->setIssueDate('1950/01/01');
$entity->setPassDate('1950/01/01');
```

But when i submit it, it show me the error as that these form  fields are required, although i set as default date as 1950/01/01. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Do you have some validation constraints related to these form fields? I mean, `NotBlank()`?

Comment: Btw, the validation error comes from the form component, right?

Comment: yes, i want to add in default value .. before i add in Builder .. code is something like this

Comment: ->add('issueDate', 'date', array('label'=>'issue Date','widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy'))

Comment: Inside entity . yes it is NotBlank ()

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the `NotBlank` symfomy validator mapping from the two fields or use the `empty_data` option which will populate default values if the hidden fields weren't filled via JavaScript like this:

```
$builder->add('passDate', 'hidden', array(
  'data' => null,
  'empty_data' => '1950/01/01'
)
```

Comment: CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Call to a member function format() on string" at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myProgramme/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateType.php line 53

Comment: Is there anyway to convert string to date in symfony 2.7?

Comment: I assumed your getters/setters are taking care of formatting because you pass a **string** to them in your question. You can either use a data transformer or just use `'empty_data' => new \DateTime('1950/01/01')`

Comment: I did exactly what you guide me and still not going through, is there anything i am missed ?

Comment: my builder is 
->add('passDate', 'hidden', array('data'=>null ,'empty_data' => new \DateTime(setPassDate('1950/01/01') )))

Comment: public function setPassDate($passDate)
    {
        $this->passDate = $passDate;

        return $this;
    }

Comment: public function getPassDate()
    {
        return $this->passDate;
    }

Comment: Error is 

Attempted to call function "setPassDate" from namespace "AppBundle\Form".

Comment: Post your controller action, model and all relevant parts of `buildForm` with all the options please. Can't debug this otherwise. You asked for how to set default values - I answered. This is another issue.